# How to use third party themes in swing application?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar

I want to use some third party themes (like synthetica http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/themes/) in my swing appliaction. i am using `eclipse ide`, got the jar file of theme and did the following modification(according to the readme file from the theme) in my code

```
try 
  {      
   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel());
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

but after this modification its showing the following error

```
 The type de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

what does this mean? i tried searching on net but cant really find any useful answers

***Contents of Readme file:***

```
System Requirements
===================

Java SE 5 (JRE 1.5.0) or above
Synthetica V2.2.0 or above

Integration
===========

1. Ensure that your classpath contains all Synthetica libraries (including
   Synthetica's core library 'synthetica.jar').

2. Enable the Synthetica Look and Feel at startup time in your application:

    import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel;

    try 
    {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the jar file to your classpath? :)

Comment: ya i added it to location where all my compiled class file are present

Comment: But did you add it to the classpath?

Comment: Ya , i did but the same error.i used the steps in this link to do it
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Answer (score 2):

It means you are missing dependant classes. If you look at the requirements it also requires "Synthetica Standard Look and Feel"

you can download it [here](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/download)

Comment: ya i have the jar file downloaded, how to add it to the project using eclipse IDE?

Comment: @swift: See my answer about how to add it to your project in eclipse.

Comment: ya jonas i added but the same error is there. 
i cant find any lib folder within my project workspace
i used the steps in this link to add it to the buildpath
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the *.jar*-file, then you need to add it to your build path in eclipse.

I.e. if you in your eclipse project have a directory *lib* where you put your *.jar*-files, then right-click on your jar-file and chose *Build Path* then *Add to Build Path*.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the issue might have been resolved as this is a very old post, but as this may contribute other current users (like myself):

- First you must add the Synthetica.jar first then add a theme. To downlaod Synthetica.jar visit this link : [jyloo.com/synthetica/download](http://jyloo.com/synthetica/download) .To download a theme try [jyloo.com/synthetica/themes](http://jyloo.com/synthetica/download)
- Right-click on you project and click on "Properties"
- On Java Build Path , select the third tab and the click "Add JARs" or "Add External JARs..." and locate the .jar files and the click "Open"
- Click "Ok" and the to enable theme, you can use this code:

  ```
  try {    
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlueMoonLookAndFeel());  
  }  catch (Exception e) {      
  e.printStackTrace();    
  }
  ```